Unexpected result from zipping two generators. How does zip work?
I have two generators, one which depends on the output of the other.
def do_work(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield i


def more_work(x):
    for i in x:
        yield i * 2


def main():
    x = do_work(5)
    y = more_work(x)
    for i, j in zip(x, y):
        print(i, j)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

When I try to zip the inputs, it seems like Python is skipping some of the values of the control variables:
0 2
2 6

Does zip continue iterating before both generators can yield at the same time?

It sounds like your misunderstanding is really about how iterators work, not about zip specifically. You can't have two consumers trying to consume the same iterator output.

@user2357112 So in this case, zip and more_work are calling next() on do_work, sequentially, which is the cause of my "unexpected" result?

FYI, I just added a possible solution to my answer. [You can flag this comment as "no longer needed" once you see it.]


Does zip continue iterating before both generators can yield at the same time?

Nothing's happening "at the same time" here: there's no concurrency. What the zip does each loop is:

Call next() on x
Call next() on y, which calls next() on x

So you can see, x is being consumed by two different things, hence it's being exhausted earlier than you expected.
Possible solution
You could use itertools.tee, which holds a buffer for you.
from itertools import tee

...

def main():
    x = do_work(5)
    x, x1 = tee(x)
    y = more_work(x1)
    for i, j in zip(x, y):
        print(i, j)

Output:
0 0
1 2
2 4
3 6
4 8


zip simply iterates over two (or more) iterators in parallel, consuming one item from each input and yielding a tuple of items.
You're getting weird results because zip and more_work are both consuming x.  Each time zip consumes an item from more_work, more_work consumes an item from x before zip can see it, so in effect each consumer is getting half the items.
What I think you would probably want to do in this case would be to have more_work itself yield its input along with its output (similar to how enumerate yields the indices of whatever it's iterating over):
def do_work(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield i


def more_work(x):
    for i in x:
        yield i, i * 2


def main():
    for i, j in more_work(do_work(5)):
        print(i, j)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

which prints the output I think you were hoping for:
0 0
1 2
2 4
3 6
4 8


I just set a breakpoint to the for loop: for i, j in zip(x, y), and just as you've deduced based on user2357112's comments, there's repetitive invocation of next() each time any of your generators are accessed.
The main issue is that when zip() tries to resolve the value of i, it invokes next() on x which is tied to a generator do_work(5), and subsequently returns 0 to i correctly.
When zip() now tries to resolve the corresponding value of j, it first attempts to decipher what y is; finds out it's tied to another generator assigned to more_work() which yet again takes as argument a generator tied to x = do_work(5). Here's your problem: do_work(5) will yield a second value during a single iteration of the for loop because we already invoked next() on do_work(5) once prior.
So at your first iteration, i = 0 and j = 2 because i now updates itself to i = 1 due to the chain of execution that invokes do_work() twice.

Now this is all confusing, so I will recommend you set a breakpoint and debug the program by observing the sequential execution and how the updating of variables unravels.
To fix the problem, since you've mentioned that you "don't want to have to hold the entire sequence in memory", you just have to introduce a third variable z with the same INITIAL value  as x then update your main function like this:
def main():
    x = do_work(5)
    z = do_work(5)
    y = more_work(z)
    for i, j in zip(x, y):
        print(i, j)

Output:
0 0
1 2
2 4
3 6
4 8


It is because you are triggering a semi recursive next call with the zip function.
Using zip yields a value from both generators, however, when the more_work function is triggered, the do_work is also called again. Thus, yielding a value from the generator another time.
Here is a better understanding of all the reasons why the lines weren't printed:

0 2 printed because it's the first call, this triggers an extra yield on the first generator, thus changing it to 1.
2 6 now the first generator is called again, so the value is 2. Here, in the second generator, it calls the first generator to yield another value, which causes the first generator to become 3, and for the second generator, it becomes 6 since it's doubled.

And now, on the next run, the first generator becomes 4 (empty now since all values were returned), the second generator now is unable to yield anymore elements, since the first generator is called again, but it's already empty.

Solution:
Here is a solution for fixing this issue, just change the first function so that it yields twice, to fix this issue:
def do_work(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield i
        yield i


def more_work(x):
    for i in x:
        yield i * 2


def main():
    x = do_work(5)
    y = more_work(x)
    for i, j in zip(x, y):
        print(i, j)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Output:
0 0
1 2
2 4
3 6
4 8

